# How to inner join and parse data as JSON using json1

Tags: sqlite, sqlite-json1

For example, let's say I've a table called **Movie** with 2 columns - [id,title]

**Data**:

```
1, killbill
2, endgame
```

and another table as
**Cast** with 2 columns - [id,name]

**Data:**

```
1, Uma
1, David
2, Robert
```

***Cast table has actors and id is same as movie.***

The output I want from SELECT query is something like:

```
1, killbill, [uma,David]
2, endgame,[Robert]
```

What I tried:

```
select m.*,json_array(c.name) from movie m inner join cast c on c.id = m.id
```

But it returns:

```
1   killbill    [David]
1   killbill    [Uma]
2   endgame     [Robert]
```

Please suggest the right way to group data. I also tried group by, but then it returns less data.

If I use `json_group_array`, I get only one movie with all cast

```
1   killbill    ["David","Uma","Robert"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must `group by` movie and use the aggregate function [`json_group_array()`](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html) instead of `json_array()`:

```
select m.id, m.title, json_group_array(c.name) names
from movie m inner join cast c 
on c.id = m.id 
group by m.id, m.title
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sNNBgeVmE7Csumop7FUJy/2).
Results:

```
| id  | title    | names           |
| --- | -------- | --------------- |
| 1   | killbill | ["David","Uma"] |
| 2   | endgame  | ["Robert"]      |
```